# Error by reading binary file with c++

Tags: c++, binary, int

I try to read in a binary file containing `char` and `int` & `double` after a header:

```
// open file
int pos = 0,n;
char str1,str2;

//string str;
ifstream fid(pfad.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
if (fid.good() != 1) {
    printf(" ++ Error: The elegant bunch file %s doesn't exist.\n",pfad.c_str());
    return 1;
}

// cut the header
while (pos<5) {
    if (fid.eof()) {
        printf(" ++ Error: elegant bunch file is strange\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fid >> str1;

    switch (pos) {
        case 0: str2 = '&'; break;
        case 1: str2 = 'd'; break;
        case 2: str2 = 'a'; break;
        case 3: str2 = 't'; break;
        case 4: str2 = 'a'; break;
    }

    if (str1 == str2){
        pos ++;
    } else {
        pos = 0;
    }
}

   // Read out the data
   fid.seekg(19,ios_base::cur);

std::cout << fid.tellg() << std::endl;
fid >> n;
std::cout << fid.tellg() << std::cout;


printf("\n\n%i\n\n",n);
printf("\nOK\n");
return 0;
```

My reading char with `fid >> str1` works just fine. If I try to do this with a `int` it produces somehow a strange behaviour. The output then gets

```
813

-10x6c4f0484

0
```

Whereby the first number is the position in the file and the second one should be the same, but it looks like a pointer to me. Can anybody maybe try to clarify me confusion?

Thanks already in advance.

Comment: *"Can anybody maybe try to clarify me confusion?"* - your question itself is written in very confusing way. Try to edit it to make it more clear what exactly your problem is please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::operator>>(std::istream&, int&)` tries to *parse* an integer from a stream of characters, it doesn't read binary data. You'll need to use the [`std::istream::read(char*, std::streamsize)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) function.

Comment: Yes this is it. Although it seems rather strang to me that you have to do it like this. But then again my experiences are normaly more with high level languages. Thx for your answer

Comment: I'd consider modern C++ to be a high-level language which allows you to go low-level if required ;-) Back to the issue: It's just a matter of semantics. There's no way for `operator>>` to know whether it should try to parse a string into a integer or whether it should read binary data. So it's up to you to know the API and its semantics. BTW: Also in the very-high-level language Python you have to call `file.read(nbytes)` for binary I/O.